# Why is this default template parameter not allowed?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, default-parameters

I have the following class:

```
template <typename Type = void>
class AlignedMemory {
public:
    AlignedMemory(size_t alignment, size_t size)
        :   memptr_(0) {
        int iret(posix_memalign((void **)&memptr_, alignment, size));
        if (iret) throw system_error("posix_memalign");
    }
    virtual ~AlignedMemory() {
        free(memptr_);
    }
    operator Type *() const { return memptr_; }
    Type *operator->() const { return memptr_; }
    //operator Type &() { return *memptr_; }
    //Type &operator[](size_t index) const;
private:
    Type *memptr_;
};
```

And attempt to instantiate an automatic variable like this:

```
AlignedMemory blah(512, 512);
```

This gives the following error:

> src/cpfs/entry.cpp:438: error: missing template arguments before ‘blah’

What am I doing wrong? Is `void` not an allowed default parameter?

Comment: Do you have any code that includes the identifier `buf` anywhere?

Comment: @Charles : `buf` is a typo. See this : http://www.ideone.com/32gVl ... something is missing before mind. :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you need to write:

```
AlignedMemory<> blah(512, 512);
```

See 14.3 [temp.arg] / 4:

> When default *template-arguments* are used, a *template-argument* list can be empty. In that case the empty `<>` brackets shall still be used as the *template-argument-list*.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
AlignedMemory blah(512, 512); //wrong syntax
```

Correct syntax is this:

```
AlignedMemory<> blah(512, 512); //this uses "void" as default type!
```

---

The error message itself gives this hint. Look at it again:

> src/cpfs/entry.cpp:438: error: **missing** template arguments **before**
>   ‘buf’

PS: I'm sure 'buf' is a typo. You wanted to write 'blah' - the name of your variable!